# difference between c++9(g++ 4.3.2) and c++ 4.0.0-8

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

what is the difference between C++(g++ 4.3.2) and C++ 4.0.0-8 and the best compilers for these.

Comment: you should also improve the rate of accepted answers

Comment: what @Benoit recommended, but in more details: there're a lot of answers to your previous questions. people spent their time trying to help you. if you think some answer is just helpful or contains interesting info - upvote them (that grey array up on the left of your questions), and select the best answer and accept it (by pressing on the accept mark below arrows)

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to appear to be version numbers of compilers available on your (unnamed) platform.

C++ proper has no such version numbers.  Instead, C++ is defined by ISO standards, generally referred to by their year of ratification.  So far we have:

> **C++-98**:  The initial standard defining the basic language, including templates, the so-  called Standard Template Library, iostreams, etc.
>
> **C++-2003**:  The first revision of the standard, making minor corrections and clarifications to C++-98.
>
> **C++-TR1(2005)**:  A (non-normative) technical report suggesting several new additions to the standard library in the std::tr1 namespace.  Notably includes boost-developed smart pointers, hash tables (std::tr1::unordered_set, etc.) and other capabilities.  These additions are expected to be officially incorporated in the upcoming C++-0x standard.
>
> **C++-0x (aka C++-2011)**:  A major extension of the language with functional constructs such as lambda and automatic type determination, as well as significant new library content mostly from [boost](http://www.boost.org).

The version numbers you mentioned appear to be release numbers from one or two particular compilers.  Generally those versions don't map directly to the C++ standards, but instead to differing (hopefully improving) levels of conformance with particular ISO standards and perhaps optimization capabilities.

Comment: As TR1 is from 2005, I strongly doubt C++2003 already included it :)

Comment: @Fred:  Whoops--you're absolutely right.  Edited accordingly.